# Split JSON file using apache PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have a JSON input file that needs to be split into multiple files based on a keyword and the output should also retain the same JSON format.

Example:

The keyword here is the value of the object EVT.NAME. Depeneding on the value it should route it to the output.

Input has three different values (KEYPRESS,TUNE,TRICK), so 3 different output files should be created.

Input:

```
    {"PV":"1.0","DEV":{"DEV_ID":"P0100011103"},"EVT":{"NAME":"KEYPRESS","ETS":1402672866844,"VALUE":{"KEY":"PLAY"}},"HOST":"XXX"}
    {"PV":"1.0","DEV":{"DEV_ID":"P0100011103"},"EVT":{"NAME":"TUNE","ETS":1402672867117,"VALUE":{"KEY":"PLAY"}},"HOST":"XXX"}
    {"PV":"1.0","DEV":{"DEV_ID":"P0100011103"},"EVT":{"NAME":"TRICK","ETS":1402672868600,"VALUE":{"KEY":"PLAY"}},"HOST":"XXX"}
    {"PV":"1.0","DEV":{"DEV_ID":"P0100011103"},"EVT":{"NAME":"KEYPRESS","ETS":1402672868888,"VALUE":{"KEY":"PLAY"}},"HOST":"XXX"}
    {"PV":"1.0","DEV":{"DEV_ID":"P0100011103"},"EVT":{"NAME":"TRICK","ETS":1402673179313,"VALUE":{"KEY":"FAST_FORWARD"}},"HOST":"XXX"}
```

Output1:

```
    {"PV":"1.0","DEV":{"DEV_ID":"P0100011103"},"EVT":{"NAME":"KEYPRESS","ETS":1402672866844,"VALUE":{"KEY":"PLAY"}},"HOST":"XXX"}
    {"PV":"1.0","DEV":{"DEV_ID":"P0100011103"},"EVT":{"NAME":"KEYPRESS","ETS":1402672868888,"VALUE":{"KEY":"PLAY"}},"HOST":"XXX"}
```

Output 2:

```
    {"PV":"1.0","DEV":{"DEV_ID":"P0100011103"},"EVT":{"NAME":"TUNE","ETS":1402672867117,"VALUE":{"KEY":"PLAY"}},"HOST":"XXX"}
```

Output 3:

```
    {"PV":"1.0","DEV":{"DEV_ID":"P0100011103"},"EVT":{"NAME":"TRICK","ETS":1402672868600,"VALUE":{"KEY":"PLAY"}},"HOST":"XXX"}
    {"PV":"1.0","DEV":{"DEV_ID":"P0100011103"},"EVT":{"NAME":"TRICK","ETS":1402673179313,"VALUE":{"KEY":"FAST_FORWARD"}},"HOST":"XXX"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonLoader and JsonStorage. See this article  - http://joshualande.com/read-write-json-apache-pig.

table = LOAD 'file.json' 
    USING JsonLoader('KEYPRESS:chararray, TUNE:chararray, TRICK:chararray');